# Invalid field path with Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an error with Firestore today, because I'm trying to fetch a path with a forbidden character.

```
REF_ROOT.document(currentUser.uid).collection("records").whereField(workoutName, isEqualTo: "Open 16.5 / 14.5").getDocuments
```

Is it possible to add a backslash or anything before the slash (or any forbidden character in fact), in order to proceed this request?

This is my log:

```
Invalid field path (Open 16.5 / 14.5). Paths must not contain '~', '*', '/', '[', or ']'
firebase::firestore::util::ObjcThrowHandler(firebase::firestore::util::ExceptionType, char const*, char const*, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse paths with the field data they point to.

`"Open 16.5 / 14.5"` is a perfectly legitimate value to store in a Firestore field.

Your query is this

```
REF_ROOT.document(currentUser.uid).collection("records")
                                  .whereField(workoutName, isEqualTo: "Open 16.5 / 14.5")
                                  .getDocuments
```

Which tells me that `currentUser.uid` or the `workoutName` contains the invalid character, and it's most likely `workoutName`.

Try printing that out before the call to see what prints in console.

```
print(workoutName) //probably prints this: Open 16.5 / 14.5
REF_ROOT.document(currentUser.uid).collection("records")
                                  .whereField(workoutName, isEqualTo: "Open 16.5 / 14.5")
                                  .getDocuments
```

Comment: You're right, the problem was somewhere else, my bad. Thank you!